# Can short-circuit evaluation trigger a race condition?

Tags: java, c++, security, race-condition, short-circuiting

I like code golf. In light of [CVE-2016-5195](https://dirtycow.ninja/), I was wondering if any of my "golfed" code can trigger race conditions.

Let's say we have two functions, both of which return a boolean value, and we are initializing a boolean variable called `result`:

```
result = foo() || bar();
```

In an ideal world, we have two scenarios:

1. `foo` returns `true`. Do *not* call `bar`. `result` equals `true`. **[short-circuit scenario]**
2. `foo` returns `false`. *Do* call `bar()`. `result` equals what `bar` returns.

---

*My question:* Will there ever be a time when short-circuit evaluation is violated, and `bar` is called despite `foo` returning `true`, or even worse, `bar` is called before `foo` is called, perhaps because of multi-threading? If so, can you provide a piece of code that would trigger such behavior?

Your answer may be about any language(s) in which this syntax is valid, although I suppose some languages will be more strict about this kind of thing than others.

Comment: Maybe it is implicit but you still need to do it: tag the language. Remember that C and C++ are as similar as Haskell and Prolog are.  Without a language tag we cannot answer, it is the language specification that mandates the observable behaviour of the compiled program.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for the feedback. Can I tag it with two languages?

Comment: @彩音M: please do not tag c++ and java at the same time. The answers might be very different

Comment: @ThomasWeller Removed Java tag. If I want to know the behavior of different languages, do I need to re-ask this question...?

Comment: Does your question apply to language X? Do you want an answer for language X? Then tag it as such. Multiple language tags are OK.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: how shall someone answer the question if he is only proficient in one language? Say I could give a 100% answer for Java, but no C++ answer at all. That's not good.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, we can talk about that on meta.

Comment: Re: bounty, I don't see what kind of detail you are expecting.

Comment: How do you imagine that such a problem could arise?

Answer (score 12):

Race conditions occur when the outcome of a series of operations depends on the sequence upon which they are executed.

The `&&` and `||` operators in C++ *guarantee* left-to-right evaluation and to not evaluate the second operator if the first one is false / true, respectively. Since the sequence of operations is guaranteed, there is no race condition between operations of `foo` and operations of `bar`. There can still be race conditions between the operations *in each one*, though.

Code that violates the aforementioned guarantees is not C++ code, and likewise conforming C++ compilers will never emit code that violates those guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

The case you are referring to is not a race condition. 
Let's get back again your question:

> Will there ever be a time when short-circuit evaluation is violated,
>   and bar is called despite foo returning true, or even worse, bar is
>   called before foo is called, perhaps because of multi-threading?

I guess the right question would be:

Will there ever be a time when ***bar*** is called **AFTER** ***foo*** is called with **false** result, but while it's called ***foo*** will return **true** if will be called **again**?

Ok, let's do some code with potential `race condition` state.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 0x1000
char globalBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

bool foo() { // have user an access to the path_to_file file?
   return access(path_to_file, 0666) != 0; // path_to_file declared somewhere
}

bool bar() {
    FILE *file = fopen(path_to_file, "r");
    if (file == NULL) return false;
    char *ptr = gfets(globalBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file);
    if (ptr == NULL) return false;
    return true;
}
...
result = foo() || bar(); // if foo is false, then user have an access
printf("%s", globalBuffer);
```

Let's imagine that we can control path_to_file.

Race condition will be occuried, if we make an infinite loop like this

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    ln -s /path/to/good/access/file /path/to/file
    rm -f /path/to/file
    ln -s /etc/shadow /path/to/file
done
```

After some attempts, if your application has suid bit - I will read contents of the /etc/shadow

But let's return back to your question:

No, no way. If `foo` will return true, `bar` not will be called. Even from other thread, if you have multi-threading. Each thread has its own registers, own stack. So, in case of two function calls in the same expression you should beleive to the c++ standard. But it doesn't mean that you code is safe. And race condition one of 100 possible problems.

Comment: What you're demonstrating is properly known as a TOCTOU bug - Time-Of-Check-Time-Of-Use. It's typical of ancient POSIX code that couldn't rely on modern APIs that do two actions atomically in the kernel and so left themselves open to races.

Comment: There are many bugs, that can be exploited in combination. I demonstrated combination of race condition with symbolic links together with TOCTTOU bug. Some other example can be NULL dereference with race condition and even UAF with race condition.

Comment: Race condition exists in multi-threading case only. My example emulates second thread with shell script to trigger TOCTTOU bug. The goal of my answer is to show that if you think that code is safe it can be still totally unsafe.

Comment: A race can exist w.r.t. not just threads but also POSIX signals (e.g. `sigprocmask()` followed by `pause()` can hang forever if a handler is invoked between the two). Otherwise yes, I agree: Code that looks safe can be totally unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

Note that C++ supports operator overloading, but that short circuiting is a feature only of builtin operators (pre c++17), not user provided overloads.

I.e. in all current versions of C++ it is unsafe to assume that short circuiting will occur unless you know both types and know that no free function operator|| is shadowing.

See for [p0145](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) for how this is changing in c++17.

(bold is additions, italics removal)

> Change paragraph 5/2 as follows: [ Note: Operators can be overloaded,
>   that is, given meaning when applied to expressions of class type
>   (Clause 9) or enumeration type (7.2). Uses of overloaded operators are
>   transformed into function calls as described in 13.5. Overloaded
>   operators obey the rules for syntax **and evaluation order** specified in
>   Clause 5, but the requirements of operand type*,* **and** value category,
>   *and evaluation order* are replaced by the rules for function call.
>   Relations between operators, such as ++a meaning a+=1, are not
>   guaranteed for overloaded operators (13.5), and are not guaranteed for
>   operands of type bool. —end note ]